# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error in Google Chrome Version 45

Tags: java, google-chrome, glassfish

I am using Java Web Start Application with sun-glassfish 3.1 and Java7 and self signed certificate. I upgraded chrome browser to version 45 and started getting ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID errors.

Before upgrade I had "Not Trusted...proceed?" click-through once and it was not asked later. Now I get ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error again and again. Strange thing is sometimes it is working and I don't get any.

I thought it might be related with Glassfish because it mostly occurs when load is high. I have seen some bug reports similar to my case but could not be sure if I'm having the same problem. I'm a novice at this area so please forgive any mistakes. Should I wait for a fix in chrome or is there  anything I could do to understand and fix the error?

Comment: Since it's a self-signed certificate, it would likely help if you imported the CA as a trusted certificate provider to Chrome. It would get rid of the "not trusted..." errors and give you a green padlock symbol in the address bar. There could be a problem with the certificate itself, but the first thing to try is importing your CA.

Comment: Hello @Mike thanks for the answer but it is not a valid solution for me because I cannot force other users to add certificate to chrome. I have to solve this problem without forcing users to do anything.

Comment: It sounds like an error in Chrome. I use self-signed certificates for non-public websites and, although I get a warning in browsers without the certificate installed, there is always a click through.

Comment: Just to be sure - do you get the "Advanced" link as seen in this screenshot? http://i.imgur.com/OmGeJlG.png if you do, click that and you should be given another link to proceed. (I had assumed you already knew about that, but I don't know what Chrome version you're coming from)

Comment: Yes I get "Advanced" link. The problem was even if I proceed it keeps asking. By the way, I just tried version 46 beta and I could not reproduce. They might have fixed it.